# How do I solve such inequality?

Tags: inequality

$$\frac{x+6}{x-6}\left(\frac{x-4}{x+4}\right)^2+\frac{x-6}{x+6}\left(\frac{x+9}{x-9}\right)^2<\frac{2x^2+72}{x^2-36}$$

I'm quite lost here, can't spot anything to start working from.

Comment: I would try to rewrite the inequality using that

$$\frac{x+a}{x-a}=\frac{x-a}{x-a}+\frac{2a}{x-a}=1+\frac{2a}{x-a}$$

Comment: What have you tried so far for this inequality? Please provide the method, so we can assist.

Comment: Not much, actually, tried using intervals to determine maybe one side would be positive, then the next one negative, but no luck, sadly.

Comment: Yeah, then if i expand the LHS similar way i can move both to one side and factor out common multiples, but still struggling, any more help?

Comment: There is a saying: "If you are going thru hell - keep going".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{x+6}{x-6}\left(\frac{x-4}{x+4}\right)^2+\frac{x-6}{x+6}\left(\frac{x+9}{x-9}\right)^2=\frac{2(x^2+36)(x^4-71x^2+1296)}{(x-9)^2(x+4)^2(x-6)(x+6)}$$

Thus, we need to solve 
$$\frac{x^4-71x^2+1296}{(x-9)^2(x+4)^2(x-6)(x+6)}<\frac{1}{(x-6)(x+6)}$$ or
$$\frac{x(5x^2-12x-180)}{(x-9)^2(x+4)^2(x-6)(x+6)}<0,$$
which gives the answer:

$x<-6$ or $\frac{6-6\sqrt{26}}{5}<x<-4$ or $-4<x<0$ or $6<x<\frac{6+6\sqrt{26}}{5}$.

Comment: A question - how do you calculate the first expression quickly? Because reducing to a common denominator and multiplying everything seems a bit too much work, maybe there is a fast trick to spot something?

Comment: @John Robbers For example: $(x+6)^2(x-4)^2(x-9)^2+(x-6)^2(x+4)^2(x+9)^2=(x^3-7x^2-42x+216)^2+(x^3+7x^2-42x-216)^2=(2x^3-84x)^2-2((x^3-42x)^2-(7x^2-216)^2)=2(x^3-42x)^2+2(7x^2-216)^2...$